# How to mount django app at root of site on Apache?

Tags: linux, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm following the documentation here:

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

I'm using apache2 on Debian

I change the settings by editing apache2.conf

When I mount my app like this,

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /path/to/mysite
```

and it works when I browse 127.0.0.1/app/.

However, when I try to mount my app at root like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite
```

and I browse 127.0.0.1/ , the default page "It works!" is shown by apache

The option

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/mysite
```

in apache2.conf doesn't work, too.

Comment: It is a bad idea to set ``DocumentRoot`` to be where your project code is, because if you stuff up your Apache configuration, what you did increases risk that someone can download your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the location of the wsgi script.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myproj/src/myproj/wsgi.py process-group=myproj
```